# installing fuzzystrmatch in postgres 9.0.23 for windows

Tags: windows, postgresql

I have PostGres 9.0.23 installed on my Windows 64-bit computer. I want to use the Levenshtein function but cannot use it as it is not available. Please tell me how to install fuzzystrmatch?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use PostgreSQL 9.0 any more, it's unsupported.

Extensions were introduced in 9.1, so you'll have to install the [fuzzystrmatch contrib](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) by [running the corresponding SQL script](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/contrib.html).

Comment: Thank you. I figured out that running the sql on 9.0 works. I am going to move to 9.1.